# show off content that is not able to come forward

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

It is such that when you click on submit then the content will appear in a box,

the problem is that the content does not appear at all in some places. even though I click on the submit button.

this is how I download content from the database to be displayed on the page.

PHP / HTML

```
if ($stmt = $this->mysqli->prepare('SELECT title, filenavn FROM dwopgaver')) { 
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($title, $filenavn);
    while ($stmt->fetch())
    {
        if($point >= 30)
        {
            ?>
            <div class="dwopgave">
                <strong><?php echo $title;?></strong>
                <form action="#" method="post">
                    <input type="submit" name="dw" value="Download" class="dwopgavenuogher">
                </form>
                <div class="dwbox">
                    <a href="/opgaveFile/<?php echo $filenavn;?>" target="_black"><?php echo $title;?></a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <?php
        } else {
            ?>
            <div id="error"><?php echo $fornavn . " " . $efternavn;?> har ikke 30 point på din bruger!, <b>Du har kun <?php echo $point;?> point</b></div>
            <?php
        }
    }
    $stmt->close();
}
```

Jquery

```
$(".dwopgavenuogher").click(function() {
    $(".dwbox").slideDown("slow",function() {
    });
});
```

CSS

```
.dwopgave {
    padding: 2px 3px;
    margin: 2px 0px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #999;
    clear: both;

    text-align: center;
}
.dwbox {
    display: none;
    color: Red;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

The problem is such that it will not come out of it, and I wish, for example containing 1 also shows only content 1'en content.

i have make its here now:

```
   <div class="dwopgave">
<button id="SlideToDown"><?php echo $title;?> - Download nu</button>
<div class="dwbox">
    <a href="/opgaveFile/<?php echo $filenavn;?>" target="_black"><?php echo $title;?></a>
</div>
</div>
<script> 
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".dwopgavenuogher").click(function() {
        $(".dwbox").slideDown("slow",function() {
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

If I do it like this so all come forward and being shown but for example if I click on hey hey then the content will also be displayed, it will not do as I show here:

Se [imega here](http://billedeupload.dk/?v=Gb4FV.png)

Comment: Are you looking for something like - `$(this).parent().next(".dwbox").slideDown("slow",function() {});`, so it only shows the next/sibling `.dwbox`? Could you recreate your issue as a jsfiddle - http://jsFiddle.net

Comment: @Sean her can you show my code; http://jsfiddle.net/yLuR7/2/

Comment: With your change in code, try `$(this).next(".dwbox").slideDown("slow",function() {});`  see http://jsfiddle.net/yLuR7/3/

Answer (score 0):

Did you put the jquery code inside the ready function?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // your code...
});
```

Comment: I edit some of my code, try look at the nederes part of the code if it is :)